# Grant access with Apex Manage Sharing

Tags: permissions, apex-managed-sharing

If OWD for an object is "private" and the permission set for the user is "Read only" can I assign the "Edit" permission with Apex Manage Sharing?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't provide edit privileges to records using apex manual sharing. As `Apex Manual Sharing` just share record which act like record level sharing but user should have edit privileges to object and field to perform edit operation on it.